# How can I know how many packets are still available in the txqueue using C code?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, linux-device-driver

I need to write a C code to check the status of a network device txqueue to know if there is still not sent packets, or how many packets queued in the queue.

Comment: Look at source code of tools which show the queue size. Easily available with `apt-get source` or equivalent.

Comment: Specifically, look at source for `tc` bundled with the `iproute2` source.  I'm thinking whatever `tc -s qdisc` does might be what you're after.  It probably uses either `ioctl` calls on a socket or `netlink` sockets (see `man netlink`) of some sort.  You may also find some info in the kernel documentation.